# How to create full width dropdown with sticky items?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I need full-width dropdown and items in the dropdown must be sticky to the parent item. Check screenshots.

I am using `React` and `React Bootstrap`. I will be glad to get any advice or help. Thank you.

[image: screenshots 1]
[image: screenshots 2]
[image: screenshots 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself. So check it if you have the same thing to do:
[My Solution](https://codesandbox.io/embed/weathered-framework-dcb94?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FNav.jsx&theme=dark)

Answer (score 1):

This might be the solution you're looking for, let me know if you need any changes.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #a1a1a1;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content .header {
  background: red;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">   
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<div style="padding:16px">
  <h3>Responsive Mega Menu (Full-width dropdown in navbar)</h3>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: The code is working properly, see here https://jsfiddle.net/ujjawalpoonia/cw8toer4/3/

Comment: this is not what i need
the links are not sticky

Comment: You can add some padding from left in Desktop devices.